# How to trigger an event when clicking a '<A href' tag in dynamic text box?

Tags: actionscript-3, text, dynamic

I need to track href links in a dynamic textField. ie the text is loaded as XML.
So somehow I need to listen for an event when this a href tag is clicked in the dynamic textField.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you be more specific? I dont think flash reders <a> tags as active links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dispatch events from link the following way:

```
<a href='event:http://www.adobe.com'>Navigate to Adobe.com.</a>
```

Then listen to `TextEvent.LINK`.

```
textField.addEventListener(TextEvent.LINK, linkHandler);

public function linkHandler(event:TextEvent):void {                
    // Open the link in a new browser window.
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest(event.text), '_blank')
}
```

[Read more](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=textcontrols_04.html).